# DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on this signup with firebase and storing user details in the firestore.

I've been able to register user successfully but when I'm adding the details to the database, I get error on one of the fields. undefined. 
When i try without the `catchPhrase` field it works.

Here is my code: auth.service.ts

```
    emailSignUp(email: string, password: string) {
return this.afAuth.auth
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(credential => {
    this.customSetUSerData(credential.user);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
customSetUSerData(user: User) {
const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
const userData: User = {
  uid: user.uid,
  email: user.email,
  displayName: user.displayName,
  catchPhrase: user.catchPhrase
}; // photoURL: user.photoURL,
return userRef.set(userData).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Here is register.component.html

```
      ngOnInit() {
this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  password: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$'),
      Validators.minLength(6),
      Validators.maxLength(25),
      Validators.required
    ]
  ],
  region: ['', []],
  catchPhrase: ['', [Validators.required]],
  photoUrl: []
});
   }

  get email() {
return this.signUpForm.get('email');
   }
   get password() {
return this.signUpForm.get('password');
   }

  get catchPhrase() {
return this.signUpForm.get('catchPhrase');
  }
   get photoUrl() {
return this.signUpForm.get('photoUrl');
  }
  signup() {
// console.log(this.email.value + this.password.value + this.catchPhrase.value);
return this.auth.emailSignUp(this.email.value, this.password.value);
  }
 }
```

And here is the error:

> Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field catchPhrase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit: you're trying to set a field `catchPhrase` to `undefined`, which is not a valid value.

This happens in this code:

```
catchPhrase: user.catchPhrase
```

So it seems that `user.catchPhrase` is `undefined`. This makes sense, since  Firebase Authentication user does not have a `catchPhrase` property. You're probably looking to pass some catchphrase that the user entered/selected into your code, in which case you should pass it as a separate parameter or look it up like this:

```
catchPhrase: catchPhrase
```

This would call your (read only) getter for the `catchPhrase` property:

```
get catchPhrase() {
  return this.signUpForm.get('catchPhrase');
}
```

Comment: so how do i go about it? I'm new to this..please